# How do I find players to play in person?

Tags: tournament, clubs

How do I find events (free/paid) that would allow me to play chess locally with other players?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost every city has a local chess club. You can always join your local club and find other events or activities through your club.

Comment: some cities have chess clubs.   there are many other places to find people to play other than formal clubs.  our city has no club.  some people play in the park. some play at the library.  others play in homes.

Answer (score 7):

The USCF has a registry of all USCF-sanctioned chess clubs.

[You can go here.](http://main.uschess.org/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=198)

Comment: there are many clubs that are not uscf sanctioned.  and many people play without a club in their town.

Answer (score 6):

Searching for ["chess" on Meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/find/?keywords=chess) will return any meetup groups in your area.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is  meeting people who play chess.  Google is a good starting place.  Look for clubs.  Also consider travel to tournaments.

Try meetup.  Check with libraries and churches and schools at all levels.  It may be informal not an official club that plays.

Look in the park when the weather is good. Put an ad on craigslist.  Ads on bulletin boards.  Ask people.

Play with a set in public.  Coffee shops and malls. People will see you and may want to play.

These days many prefer to play online instead of in person.  Try it.
Also there are apps and programs that play well.